# fs.writeFileSync write only certain amount every time, not all data. Javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a problem, am running programm which will run every object throug foreach and write the data inside json file, but it always stop at some point, everytime its different. It doesnt give me any error, it just stop like normal would. And i ended up with 300 objects instead of 1400 i wanted. Any help?

```
function t (){
    var jsonData =  JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync("./list.json"));
    jsonData.forEach((element) => {
      
        request('https://api.elrond.com/accounts/'+element.address+'/tokens/count',  function (error, response, html) {
            if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
                try{
             var arr = JSON.parse((cheerio.load(html))('html').text())
                }
                catch(err){console.log(err)}
             

             data = {
                address: element.address,
                ESDT_count: arr
             }
console.log(data)
try{
var myObject =  JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync("./list1.json"));
myObject.push(data);
var newData = JSON.stringify(myObject);
    fs.writeFileSync("./list1.json",newData);  
}
catch(err){console.log(err)}

        }})
        }) 
        }
       
         t();
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is because you wrote the file in the forezch loop, so every item of the array gets overwritten by the next and you end with only the last one. Store the data you want in an array then write it after the loop or change the filename using the index

Comment: Its returning me nothing. I think its beacuse of request call. How can i slow down for each to have it in 1 second interval for each object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**i solved it with delay**

```
async function a ()
{ data.forEach(async (person,i) => {
 
  setTimeout(() => {
request('https://api.elrond.com/accounts/'+person.address+'/tokens/count', async function (error, response, html) {
          if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
              try{
           var arr = await JSON.parse((cheerio.load(html))('html').text())
              }
              catch(err){console.log(err)}
              console.log(arr)
  var data ={ address: person.address ,
      staked: arr }
      var myObject =  JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync("./list1.json"));
      myObject.push(data);
      var newData = JSON.stringify(myObject);
          fs.writeFileSync("./list1.json",newData); 

      
  }})
}, i * 1000);
});

}
a()
```